# Why validation does not allow clearing the "Entry" field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, tkinter, tk-toolkit

EDIT:
So, the problem is that when you try to clear an Entry with the validation turned on, it won't work although the function is called and it will work when you uncomment "return True" at the beggining of validating function.

```
from tkinter import *
#Currying needed for callback function with args:
class curry:
    def __init__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fun = fun
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy(  )
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs and self.kwargs:
            kw = self.kwargs.copy(  )
            kw.update(kwargs)
        else:
            kw = kwargs or self.kwargs

        return self.fun(*(self.pending + args), **kw)

#Display is an tk.Entry child, with few functions as my own api
class Display(Entry):
    
    def __init__(self, root, column=0, row=0, args_grid={}, args_entry={}):
        super().__init__(root, **args_entry) 
        self.grid(column=column, row=row, **args_grid)

    def cleardisplay(self):
        print("deleting")
        self.delete(0,END)


def onclick(key,disp):
    if key=="clear":
        disp.cleardisplay()
        return

#list of all valid chars (when the validation schould return True)
VALIDCHARS=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"+","-","*","/","=")

def onValidate(validchars,char_to_validate,action):
    #return True                                        #when you uncomment this line, everything'll be fine
    if (char_to_validate in validchars): # or action==-1 or action==0:
        return True
    return False

#An actual program:
root = Tk()
vcmd=(root.register(onValidate),VALIDCHARS, '%S','%d')

args_entry={"width":40, "borderwidth":5,"validate":"key", "validatecommand":vcmd}
display = Display(root,0,0,args_entry=args_entry)

display.insert(0,"123")                         #notice, that it won't work with validation

buttonClear = Button(root,padx=40,pady=20,text="clear",command=curry(onclick,"clear",display)) 
buttonClear.grid(columnspan=3)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware that if the validation function returns `False`, the entry won't have the new characters? It's not clear why you think you need to delete a previous character that has already been validated.

Comment: Right.  If you remove those two lines, this works exactly as you expect.

Comment: As you say, when YOU change the widgets, Tk turns off validation.  You can turn it back on with `self.entry.configure(validate='key')`, but I don't think you really want to change the control at all.

Comment: Please don't copy some other code that doesn't fit your description. You claim to have a clear button, and you claim this doesn't work. Please provide a [mcve] which has a clear button, and not a bunch of code and comments that are unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: I understand, I gave this example because I was wondering why it was behaving this way and I thought if I found out it would help me in the main project (when the problem is a bit different). Give me a while, I'm working on that minimal reproducible example with main project, sorry for trouble.

Comment: And there it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onValidate` function is assuming that `char_to_validate` is a single character. When you try to insert "123" or when you try to delete more than one character, `char_to_validate` will be a string. When you insert "123", the three-character string "123" is not in the list of valid characters, since the list of valid characters is a list of individual characters. "1" is in the list, "2" is in the list, and "3" is in the list, but "123" is not in the list.

Also, since `char_to_validate` will be "123" if the entry has "123" and you click the clear button, your validation won't work because it is assuming it is only being called during insertion of a single character rather than the deletion of multiple characters. You don't want to check if "123" is in the list of valid characters if you're trying to delete them, you should only care during an insertion.

In your case, I recommend that you pass in `%P` instead of `%S` since that will tell you what the string would be if the modification is allowed. You can then iterate over all of the characters in the string and verify each one is in the list of valid characters.

```
def onValidate(validchars,chars_to_validate,action):
    for char in chars_to_validate:
        if char not in validchars:
            # there is an invalid character in the input; don't allow it.
            return False
    return True
...
vcmd=(root.register(onValidate),VALIDCHARS, '%P','%d')
```

The above will allow nothing to be in the entry, or any string of any length as long as all of the characters are in `validchars`.